# local community or neighborhood

Tags: meaning

I want to know if we can use local community and neighborhood interchangeably? Do they have same meaning or local community includes much larger area than neighborhood?

Comment: Have you tried looking up these words in a good dictionary? community is more often used about the **people** in an area, whereas neighbourhood is more often used about the **area**. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a formal definition of either *neighborhood* or *local community*, so it's impossible to say which one is larger.

To this US English speaker, the main differences are

- *neighborhood* sounds informal and natural; *local community* sounds formal and slightly stilted.
- *neighborhood* mostly refers to the geographical area, and by extension, the people in it; *local community* refers mostly to the people, and only by extension to the geographical area.  For example, in the sentence "A [water main](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/water%20main) broke, and the whole ______ was flooded", only *neighborhood* sounds natural.
- Also, a community does not necessarily refer strictly to a geographical area.  For example, everyone living in [East Boston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Boston) is part of the neighborhood, but only the Russians there are part of the *Russian community*.  I might expect a local Russian-language newspaper to use the term *local community* to refer to local Russian speakers, not everyone in the neighborhood.

Comment: Commenting on my first point to add that the theme song to *Fresh Prince of Bel-Air* would have sounded really weird if it went "...a couple of guys who were up to no good / Started making trouble in my *local community*."

Comment: If somebody says " the local community in Austin",  for instance, does he/she talk about Austinites in general then?

Comment: I would take "the local community in Austin" to mean Austinites in general if nothing else was specified.